# JSRender - Changing template dynamically

Tags: jquery, jsrender

I am using JSRender to render a template.

I am using the first example in demos -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../jsrender.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../resources/demos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>


<body>
<a href="../demos.html">JsRender Demos</a><br />
<h3>Render template against local data</h3>

<script id="movieTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">

<!-- This thing i want to change dynamically -->
<div>
{{:#index+1}}:<b>{{:Close}}</b> ({{:Open}})
</div>

</script>



<div id="movieList"></div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
var movies = [
{ name: "The Red Violin", releaseYear: "1998" },
{ name: "Eyes Wide Shut", releaseYear: "1999" },
{ name: "The Inheritance", releaseYear: "1976" }
];

// Render the template with the movies data and insert  
// the rendered HTML under the "movieList" element
$( "#movieList" ).html(
    $( "#movieTemplate" ).render( movies )
);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What i need is to change the template at runtime. That is the `<div>` contents in the `<script id=movieTemplate">`

Can anybody help me out resolve this issue.

Thanks for sharing your wisdom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the template for eample via $.getJSON and then do something like

```
$.getJSON('http://YourServer.com/yourTemplate.txt', function(res) {
$.templates({ tmpl: res });
$("#movieList").html($.render.tmpl(movies ));
});
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks Yamil! but i am unable to understand your code. Meanwhile i will try the code. Thanks again!

Comment: Understood the code now but still not working for me. I think i need to work more.

Comment: ok, there is my WORKING version:   $.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: 'http://wool/stuff/tmpl_reload.txt', 
   dataType : "text", 
   success: function (data, textStatus) { 
$.template("tadatempl", data);
$(".gradient").html($.tmpl("tadatempl",dataItems ));
}})